# VB.net Autoclick sound file play on top of each other

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I've been trying for a really long time now to play an audio file that is like a click with a Timer that clicks at the same time as the mouse clicks as an autoclicker, but I haven't gotten anything to work...

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Click_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Click.Tick

    mouse_event(mouseclickdown, 0, 0, 0, 0)

    Dim AudioFile = New MCIPlayer(Me, TextBox3.Text)
    AudioFile.Play(AudioPlayMode.Background)

    Thread.Sleep(20)

    mouse_event(mouseclickup, 0, 0, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

I used MCI Player that I found from another post, that got the best result so far, but it still doesn't work like I want it to.

I am on Visual Studio 2022 "net6.0-windows" target framework.

Comment: I just realized that it works, but it only works on a low value, because the sound gets cut out on a higher value/speed.

Comment: Maybe you can consider other libraries, for example : [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio)